# where to start building a web service layer to secure my database?

Tags: c#, winforms, database-security

I have recently built an inventory system for a c# portfolio project and I have all the main functionality of the program down, the database is built and all the passwords are hashed and somewhat secure etc, but I wanted to something a bit more technical as i think it would be good on my portfolio. I was informed that a good way to secure my database would be to build a web service layer that I would call instead of directly calling to the database and also not having my connection string saved in a variable in the program itself, but im not sure where to start with building the web service as I have never done anything before and I wanted to ask if anyone could point me in the right direction if they arent busy, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: If your database in on a different machine than the machines on which you application is running, and your application have multiple users, then it makes sense to think about introducing a Web Api layer; but if everything on running the same machine then Web Api doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don’t mind setting the database up on a different pc instead I really just want to use this to learn, and my application does have multiple users in this scenario